# Powershell if -lt problem; returns true if the condition is false

Tags: powershell, if-statement, read-host

I have a problem with small script in Powershell.
Here is my script:

```
$number = Read-Host "Enter a number"
if ($number -lt 3){
    Write-Host "Number is too low."
    break
}
```

But when I enter `25`, for example, the `if` conditional still evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Read-Host` always returns a *string*, and `-lt` performs *lexical* comparison with a string as the LHS:

```
PS> '25' -lt 3
True  # because '2' comes lexically before '3'
```

You must convert the string returned from `Read-Host` to a *number* in order to perform *numerical* comparison:

```
[int] $number = Read-Host "Enter a number"
if ($number -lt 3){
    Write-Host "Number is too low."
    break
}
```